# Why the result type of unwrapping future via for comprehension is Future?

Tags: scala, future

My code:

```
val f1 = Future[String] { "ok1" }
val fRes: Future[String] = for { r <- f1 } yield r
```

I expect `fRes` to be a String, but I get a `Future[String]`. Why?

I don't want to use `Await.result`.

```
val fRes = for { r <- Await.result(f1, Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) } yield r
```

Comment: Have a look here on how to use Futures: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: The `r` inside the for comprehension is a `String`, but the `r` you yield is a `Future[String]`. It's a good idea to read the page linked to by @RobertUdah to get a feeling what a `Future` is. A for comprehension is just suggary syntax for `flatMap`s + `map`. In your case `for { r <- f1 } yield r` is just the same as `f.map(r -> r)`, so it's logical you end up with the same `Future[String]` you began with.

Comment: You do not get a String because the for comprehension does not block to wait for the future to complete.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of `for` and `yield` does not "unwrap" the `Future`.
In practice that is a good thing.

So every kind of `Option`, `Try`, `List` or as the fancy functional people call it `Applicative Functor` keeps it's type this way.

Due to this property you can code *inside* the `for { <- }` as if the code was "unwrapped" but only because it is made sure that outside of the code the things stays wrapped.

It may be clearer when on looks at what a `for-comprehension` does under the hood. It is syntactic sugar for chained `map` and `flatMap` operations.

```
val x: Option[_] = Some(5).map{ i => 
  // i is "unwrapped" here 
  (i * i).toString  
}

val x: Option[_] = for {
  i <- Some(5)
} yield i.toString // i unwrapped for the for comprehension but will keep Option type
```

If you want to access the future value at the end and do something in a synchronuous program flow with it you only have to options

As @Robert Udah suggest you can use `onComplete` and have a callback function or you have to use `Await`.